# Creating a List of objects of a particular type only

Tags: c#, beginner

I'm using an `interface IloadPattern` on deriving 3 classes from it `LinearLoadingPattern` , `JointsLoadingPattern` , `AreaLoadingPattern`. At some point, I'm creating a list all the objects created from those classes.

At a later point, I want to retrieve list of a particular object (`JointsLoadingPattern`) from the above list, I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Below is the way I'm doing it.

```
public List<JointsLoadingPattern> GetJointLoads()
{
    List<JointsLoadingPattern> jointLoads =  new List<JointsLoadingPattern>();

    foreach(ILoadPattern loadCase in AllLoadCases)
    {
        if(loadCase.GetType() ==typeof(JointsLoadingPattern))
        {
            jointLoads.Add((JointsLoadingPattern)loadCase);
        }
    }

    return jointLoads;
}
```

Comment: you could use linq: e.g. something like this: `AllLoadCases.Where(case => case.GetType() == typeof(JointsLoadingPattern)).ToList()`  - i like the LINQ way because it is less verbose. but is exactly the same as what you are already doing right now.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: Linq also provides an `OfType` method: `AllLoadCases.OfType<JointsLoadingPattern>().ToList()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the *LINQ* extension method `IEnumerable.OfType<TResult>()`, it returns any elements matching the type of the specified generic type argument:

```
var jointLoads = AllLoadCases.OfType<JointsLoadingPattern>();
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<JointsLoadingPattern>`, you can always call `.ToList()` to convert it.

**Update**

As noted in the comments, since `OfType<TResult>` uses the `is` operator internally, it will also return any sub-types of `TResult` type. If you want to avoid this you can write your own extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> OfExactType<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        where TResult : T
    {
        return OfExactType<TResult>(source);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> OfExactType<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        return OfExactTypeImpl<TResult>(source);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TResult> OfExactTypeImpl<TResult>(IEnumerable source)
    {
        var type = typeof(TResult);
        foreach (var t in source)
        {
            if (t.GetType() == type)
            {
                yield return (TResult)t;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
AllLoadCases.OfExactType<ILoadPattern, JointsLoadingPattern>();
AllLoadCases.OfExactType<JointsLoadingPattern>();
```

The main difference between the 2 being, that in 1 case you will get a compile-time error when you attempt to provide invalid types, while in the other case this, will be ignored and it will simply return nothing.

Comment: This is what I would do, but I would clarify that this will return all subtypes of `JointsLoadingPattern` as well, which I believe is different from what the OP was doing in their original post.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach good catch, updated the answer.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach since OP is using classes based on the `ILoadPattern` so it doesn't really matter... I doubt he has any descendants of the `JointsLoadingPattern` - actually it never matters and if it does then there is something else wrong with the code. I have never had any case where simple `OfType` wouldn't do the job. I would worry if it didn't work and I would start to think about the design again.

Comment: @t3chb0t, I know it shouldn't matter if everything is crafted correctly, and I would personally use `OfType`, I just wanted to point out that the solution is technically different from the original code.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach true, on the other hand I believe OP might not  know the `is` and `as` operators (yet) so he did it with `==` ;-)

Comment: Parameter validation and `yield return` doesn't mix well. To get immediate parameter validation you need to split the iteration part into a private (or local) implementation function: [See Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Plzkm6)

Comment: @Johnbot updated the answer to reflect that, thanks!

Comment: @Johnbot could you elaborate on that? It's a very strage theory. The first version was perfectly fine. I always do it like that...

Comment: @t3chb0t it seems that iterators are way too lazy. They defer the whole method execution until the `Enumerator.MoveNext()` is requested.

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of creating lazy iterators? I'd never split it like that... waste of time ;-) in fact, I might even use the `??` exception expression and validate the argument inside the `foreach` loop `foreach (var item in source ?? throw new ...)`

Comment: It's usually done that way (always in the framework) because it's confusing if you get an `IEnumerable` from somewhere and you slap on some additional filters and then get an exception when you try to consume it. It should fail early so you can easily find the source of the error. See also https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/18/gotcha-around-iterator-blocks/

Comment: @Johnbot ok, but then it's no longer lazy... it's half-lazy, or semi-lazy it's someting not worth the effort... besides a stack trace already contains the necessary information and tests should discover such mistakes... it's an interesting technique but very expensive and the claim that _It's usually done that way (always in the framework)_  doesn't seem to be true because none of the linq extensions does that [system.linq.enumerable](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,577032c8811e20d3)

Comment: @t3chb0t It's eager parameter validation and fully lazy sequence evaluation. It's the best of both worlds and it's exactly how it's done in `System.Linq.Enumerable` in your link. Validate parameters defer enumeration.

Comment: @Johnbot I stand corrected! I've been here for so long and you're the first person ever mentioning that :-| better late then never, thx for having patience with me ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t to be fair I have read almost everything by Eric Lippert and Jon Skeet. They point out a lot of pitfalls and how to handle them gracefully.